# Adding full background slider on front page

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a full background slider on the front page of a WordPress website. The issue is that when I place any slider, the content div starts to appear infront of the slider, causing the slider not to show at all. Please guide me how can I remove the posts area so that the slider can show up properly. Thanks.
Here is my [site](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/learning/).

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one
 * of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query,
 * e.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: theres no slider on the link?

Comment: @David: I have removed the slider.

Comment: its hard to answer without seeing what is happening.